# HTMLDivElement not toggling

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

you will find my page [here](http://nos.x10.mx/).

The issue that I'm having all of a sudden, is that when you click the start button on the lower left-hand corner of the document AFTER CLICKING IT ONCE and clicking on 'Media', the menu div will not toggle.

I've tried debugging and looking at the div in Chrome, and when I set the display of it manually, and check the div (by typing "menu" into the console [the variable for it]), it shows the updated display, but the actual page is not showing the change.

So, step by step:
1. Click the start button
2. Click on "Media".
3. Watch and ponder as the menu div will not toggle afterwards, even when you click on the start button again

Any ideas? I think it has something to do with the function that I use to open a "window".

Comment: If possible, could you please post the relevant markup and code? It would also help to provide a demo of the part that is not working on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). This would make it much easier and faster for others to help you with your issue, as it will let others focus on just the problem as opposed to trying to debug your entire web app on a live site.

Comment: You should use jQuery or any other framework for these things. They are great and make your code easier to debug.

Comment: What if your page becomes unavailable anymore or you fixed the problem? Then the question is incomplete and becomes useless (it is probably already too localized, SO is not a debugging service). We want questions to useful to future visitors too!

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that by using `document.getElementById("screentop").innerHTML+=all;` you redefine the content of `screentop` and also the menu.
To fix it you simply need to redefine `menu` after adding the window.

Your function should look like this:

```
function openWin(url,icon,title)
{
//...
var all="...";
document.getElementById("screentop").innerHTML+=all;
menu=document.getElementById("menu");
//...
}
```